# How do I use SL4A for running JRuby on Android?

Tags: java, android, sl4a

I've been looking for a way to run JRuby scripts in Android. I found something called SL4A:

> brings scripting languages to Android by allowing you to edit and
>   execute scripts and interactive interpreters directly on the Android
>   device.

And one of the supported languages is, apparently, JRuby.

However, I don't understand how to use this at all:

If you go to the [downloads page](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20Size%20Type%20DownloadCount) you can find some stuff named `jruby_for_android.apk`. But I have the impression this is not what I'm supposed to be looking for (shouldn't I be downloading some sort of JAR file instead?)

How do I use SL4A for JRuby on Android?

Comment: You might also consider Ruboto: http://ruboto.org/

Comment: in SA4A, go in Menu --> view --> interpreters

then Menu --> add --> JRuby

it will download the .apk file for JRuby, install it, start it

in the app click install,

now in SL4A you can create and launch JRuby script or star an interactive console in Menu --> view --> interpreters

Comment: @XcinnaY: but from my own Java code?